# Checking a value in another workbook that is locked and protected by a password - vba excel

Tags: excel, vba, xlsx, xlsm

I have two excel files named 1 and the other 2
File 1 is the code used to achieve the value in file 2
I have typed a value into a cell in the range ( A1 ) in file 2
And I check this value from file 1. If the value is true, it gives a true message, and if the value is false, it gives an error message
This is done and Workbook 2 is closed
The code works correctly in the unprotected workbook only

- But I want this procedure to be done so that the workbook 2 is locked and protected by a password
  I tried but could not verify the value and the workbook is locked and password protected
  I need your help in modifying this code, please, so that I can check a value in a locked and password protected workbook

  ```
  Sub Check()

        Dim con As Object, rst As Object, tFilePath As String

        Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
        Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

        tFilePath = ThisWorkbook.path & "\test1.xlsx"

        con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                 "Data Source=" & tFilePath & ";" & _
                 "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=NO';"
        rst.Open "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A1:A1]", con, 3, 1

        If rst.Fields(0).Value = "909" Then
               MsgBox "true", 64
        Else
               MsgBox "Error", 64
        End If

        rst.Close: Set rst = Nothing
        con.Close: Set con = Nothing
  End Sub
  ```

Comment: Related thread: https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?842899-RESOLVED-How-to-get-data-from-a-password-protected-closed-excel-workbook

Comment: There is no solution to my problem in this link

Comment: Seemed to me from that link that: "Yes, the Jet and ACE Providers' Excel IISAMs do not contain the logic to decrypt any of the encryption types used by various versions of Excel. So a trick is to make sure Excel already has the Workbook open using the password. It looks like this causes Excel to create a de-encrypted IStorage within the file temporarily, and that's what the IISAM needs to work with."   That would be the solution.  Did you try that?